# How to remove unwanted '\n' from output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file_4 = open('numbers.txt','r')
number_lines = 0
lines = file_4.readlines()[1:]
for file_4 in lines:
    number_lines += 1
print(lines)
print(number_lines)

output: ['2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5']
         4
```

My text file has 5 lines

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want the output to skip the first line, and display the rest.
How can I get rid of the `/n` and also how can I print each of these numbers on a different row instead of on one?

Comment: If you're going to read all the lines at once, you might as well use `.read().splitlines()`, which will trim the newline characters for you.  But better yet, use `for line in file_4` and `rstrip()`.

Comment: Note that you use the `file_4` variable in two different ways: as the file object and also as a line of the file. The second overwrites the first, so you have no way to do anything more with the file, such as close it. Change it to `for line in lines:` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix may be to just change the `for`-loop variable:

```
file_4 = open('numbers.txt','r')
number_lines = 0
lines = file_4.readlines()[1:]
for line in lines:       # do not reuse previous variable here 
    number_lines += 1
    print(line.rstrip()) # strip the newline
print(number_lines)
```

seems to give your expected output:

```
2
3
4
5
4
```

Answer (score 1):

open the file. `f.readlines()` returns each line in the text file in a list.

Since a list is indexed from 0. `list[1:]` will skip the first one and give the rest.

```
with open("stack.txt") as f:
    txt_list = f.readlines() #That's a list
    for item in txt_list[1:]: #skip the first one
        print(item)
```

output:

```
2

3

4

5

>>>
```

And the `\n` is nothing but a special character denoting a new line. From your input you read multiple lines each having a **new line** character at the end. Also `print` prints each one in a new line. That's the reason for (Two newlines) gap between two numbers in above output.

You can join the list and print like this. Since each already has a **new line** character in it. What you are doing is printing the entire list in your code.
yours:

```
output: ['2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5']
```

Try this:

```
with open("stack.txt") as f:
    txt_list = f.readlines()
    out = ''.join(txt_list[1:])
print(out)
```

output:

```
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: You can also might also want to mention "1\n".strip() as another way to remove the undesired newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.read().splitlines()`:

```
file_4 = open('numbers.txt','r')
lines = file_4.read().splitlines()[1:]      # .read().splitlines() will trim the newline chars
number_lines = len(lines)                   # We don't need a loop to count the number of lines
                                            #   We can use the `len` function.
print(lines)                                
print(number_lines)
```

But this leaves `file_4` open, and you're reading the entire file into memory unnecessarily.

Here, using a context manager, looping over the file's lines, and using `.rstrip()` to trim the newline characters:

```
with open('numbers.txt','r') as file_4:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for (i,line) in enumerate(file_4) if i > 0]

number_lines = len(lines)
print(lines)                                
print(number_lines)
```

Comment: How can I also print the line number that each line is on?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:-

```
file_4 = open('numbers.txt','r')
number_lines = 0
lines = file_4.readlines()[1:]
# here we used map() to apply strip() function on each list item to remove \n
lines = map(str.strip, lines)
for file_4 in lines:
    number_lines += 1
# here we use join() with \n to print list item with new line.
print('\n'.join(lines))
print(number_lines)
```

output:-

```
2
3
4
5
4
```

Answer (score 0):

A file is an iterator, which means you can use things like `next` and `enumerate` directly on the file, instead of reading the entire thing into memory at once. Use `strip` to remove the trailing newline. (`strip` actually removes all leading and trailing whitespace; `line.lstrip('\n')` would remove specifically trailing newlines.)

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as file_4:
    next(file)  # skip the first line
    for count, line in enumerate(file_4, start=1):
        print(line.strip())
    print("Length:", count)
```

`enumerate` basically numbers the lines (here, starting at 1), with `count` being the current line number. After this loop exits, `count` is still the number of the last line, which is also the total number of lines.